# How exactly find out length of ADT vector in C which is type of uint64_t?

Tags: arrays, c, uint64

I am trying to find out how to find the length of an ADT array type of uint64_t in C.

The code that provides the function for find length of array:

```
void func(uint64_t *arr , const char *restrict sep){
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("Size of  vektor: %d", size);
}
```

**I am not able to change any variables because it is prohibited by its creator  of whole code I can only implement some functions**.

code in vector.h file

```
/* Exported types --------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*! Data type that is stored in the vector. */
typedef uint64_t Vector_DataType_t;

/*! Structure that describes the vector. */
typedef struct {
  /*! Internal pointer to allocated memory. */
  Vector_DataType_t *items;

  /*! Number of currently allocated cells. */
  size_t size;

  /*! Pointer to the next empty cell. */
  Vector_DataType_t *next;

  /*! Number of cells allocated during expanding. */
  size_t alloc_step;
} Vector_t;
```

main.c file in which I am suppose to implament functionality (I can't post here whole bcse there is more than 200 lines)

```
int main(void)
{
  bool run = true;
  Vector_DataType_t n;
  printf("Vector test program\n"
         "Type the default size of array and the size of incrementation.\n"
         "Size:\n");
  Vector_t *vector;
  {
    size_t size;

    if (io_utils_get("%zu", &size) == true) { // Change from "false" to true
          return 0;
    }

    printf("Incrementation:\n");

    size_t step;
    if (io_utils_get("%zu", &step) == false) {
      return 0;
    }

    vector = Vector_Create(size, step);
  }

  if (vector == NULL) {
    printf("Memory for vector was not allocated successfully.\n");
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: What you wrote makes no sense. For example what is sizeof(uint64_t[0])?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Hi it is trying to divide lenght I suppouse that part is not mine I found it somewhere it also seems like complete nonsene to me

Comment: What is an "STL array in C"?

Comment: It doesn't make sense because 1) STL is a C++ thing, not a C thing, and 2) this code uses keywords (actually typedef aliases) for variable and function names.

Comment: I am sorry guys I just edited that thing it is ADT vector

Comment: An ADT for an array type that doesn't provide a way to find the size of the array is a feeble ADT (not really worthy of the name.  The whole point of creating an ADT is to make it easy to use the type — and a vector ADT that doesn't let you know the length of the vector is worse than pathetic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know I didnt write that code my task is only to implament some functions into it. It also has it's own tests but just btw.

Comment: You need to provide a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that showcases how this function is defined, how its arguments are constructed, and how it is called. Give us something that compiles, or at least comes close. This is a broken snippet currently.

Comment: You've not given us the details of the ADT which means it is hard to help.  A simple pointer to `uint64_t` is not adequate to be an ADT — C provides that level of abstraction.  An ADT normally uses a structure type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I edited it so it will be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find the size of an array passed as a pointer into a function.

The compiler has no way of knowing how big it is, either

- pass in the length as an arg
- have a sentinel value, 0, -1, MAX_INT etc

I have ignored the fact that your code very messsed up , I assume you are trying to do this

Note NOTE ==== this code does not work ===================

```
 void func(uint64_t *arr , const char *restrict sep){
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("Size of  vektor: %d", size);
}
```

Comment: I know but it is what our teacher want from us to implament there is stated `get vector lenght` but he calls vector array of type uint64_t.

Comment: I assume the same it is messed up but I got it from friend who is not so good  in C

Comment: Should probably make it more clear that the example code in this answer is non-functional.

Comment: @Oka - good point